# Flexibly getting a list of printers for a computer on a domain

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to work on a script to call all printers including network printers for a computer on a domain. I first found how to do this for one computer:

```
$printerList = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Select-Object Name
```

Without including the environmental variable part '$env:' I was only able to get a list of local printers not any network/shared printers.

My specific issue came up when trying to have the -ComputerName parameter be another variable that was an expandable string. This is important since I will need the script to be able to take a user input and have the command run without them having to manually type it out. I would run something like this:

```
$a = '$env:'+"$ComputerName" 

$printerList = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName $a | Select-Object Name
```

But then I get the error:

```
Get-CimInstance : The WS-Management service cannot process the request because port $ComputerName:port/wsman is invalid.
+ ... Printers3 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ErrorAction Sto ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
```

Not sure what this means but it is strange that it works manually but not when trying to expand the string.

Comment: Please read [`about_Environment_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1). What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, if you are trying to query a remote computer and assuming `$ComputerName` holds the name of said computer, you can just `-ComputerName $ComputerName` without the `$env:`.

Comment: Tried it that way. Querying with using `-ComputerName $ComputerName` will not give me the network/shared printers. Will read more on the environmental variables

Comment: Why can't you use Get-Printer, it appears to do exactly what you want - shows all printers including networked

Comment: Get-Printer gives me a message that Spooler services are not reachable. It has probably been disabled or blocked by our Sys Admins for members on my team. I do not think I would be able get that access so I have been trying to get it to work with Get-CimInstance

Comment: So you are saying that when you use for example `-ComputerName examplehost01` you only see those printers installed on `examplehost01` but you don't see those network printers added on `examplehost01`. Is that right? If so, are you sure `examplehost01` has network printers added and the cmdlet is not displaying them?

Comment: Also IIRC network path-connected printers are stored in the user's registry, so I would be surprised if those were in the list when querying remotely.

Comment: @Santiago Yea it appears not to list network printers done that way. I used multiple computers to test but one is my own where I know there are network printers connected it and the funky command from earlier does return a list with those printers: `$printerList = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Select-Object Name`. I should not that I am running these commands from a VM with elevated permissions so I am not querying my own computer using my own computer

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a way of testing this myself hence I'll not be able to help you but if it is as @Bill_Stewart commented then you'll be in trouble unless for example `icm -ComputerName exampleComputer1 { Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer }` returns a different result than `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ComputerName exampleComputer1`.

Comment: Was able to successfully query the network printers using the invoke-command function to remote query the registry. `$scriptblock={
   Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users\$_\Printers\Connections -Recurse -ea ignore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name }}
   
  $printers = invoke-command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -computername $computername`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to successfully query the network printers using the invoke-command function to remote query the registry.

```
$scriptblock={
            Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty
            PSChildName | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_Users\$_\Printers\Connections -Recurse -ea ignore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name}
}                   

$printers = invoke-command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -computername $computername
```